# How to build a custom PHP Mysql or PDO function

Tags: php, mysql, function, class, pdo

Recently I seem to be writing nearly the same sql statements and I have to use PHP for looping and error reporting, so I'm trying to write something general that will shorten my code extensively. I'm still learning programming.

I don't know if I need to use classes or what, but here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
/////////q = query, f = fetch type(loop or single object), r = row;
function dbQuery($q, $f, $r){
global $con;    
$query = mysqli_query($con, $q) or die(mysqli_error($con));
if ($f = 'loop'){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        echo $r;
        } 
    } else if ($f='single'){
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        echo $r;
    }
///////////or prepared statements////////// 
}
dbQuery("SELECT * FROM music WHERE perms = 'a' limit 50", $f='loop', $r="<div>".$row['title']."</div>"
);
```

I want something like the following, I know its not write but I want to be able to have the function above return row results to the function's arg.

```
dbQuery($f='loop'){ /////////// I really don't know the corrent way for this//// 
    $q= "SELECT * FROM music WHERE perms = 'a' limit 50";
    $r="<div>".$row['title']."</div>";
    ////////and breaking out of php////
    ?>
    <section><?php echo $row['duration']; ?></section>
    <?php
    }
```

Please do recommend materials I can check out.

Comment: Look at prepared statements, they are good for security and they can allow you to run the same query multiple times with different values easily.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use some framework like Laravel or some query builder class. There are tons of them. If for some reason, you will like to create your own, please do not use mysql function, since is deprecated. Personally, I will prefer PDO over mysqli (this is just a preference) make sure to prepare statements. Check this link out, it will help you with your project

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Im ok with PDO i just wanted to build a query builder class.

Comment: Awsome @Relm. That is a cool project. I just sharing with you, how mysql query builder looks like in Laravel. I think they did some fantastic job. You might want to check they source code and get some ideas. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Comment: great,  I'm looking at it, my only problem is that I'm suppose to bring the entire Laverel library to my code and also adapt to its syntax, that is a bit of an overkill for the task im trying to achieve here. I think if we can try and come up with something simple with my current small problem for mysqli (as an example, I'll change it to PDO), that'll be fine.

Comment: And do realise that I still want to write sql statements in full, I just don't want to repoeat error reporting and all else that I can tie to some class or function.

Comment: I see your point. Well, good look. It sound like a cool mini-project. Have fun